# Removing subtasks in React, with hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a problem with removing subtasks in my to-do app. I want to remove selected subtask from "Domain", istead handleRemoveSubtasks removes all of the subtasks together.

Here is my sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/weathered-paper-niyc3

Removing subtasks is in

```
const handleRemoveSubtasks = subtaskId => {
    useList(
      list.map(el => {
        console.log(el.tasks);
        console.log(subtaskId);
        console.log(el.tasks.filter(ele => ele.id !== subtaskId));
        return el.tasks.filter(ele => ele.id !== subtaskId);
      })
    );
  };
```

Comment: What is not working in the sandbox?

Comment: I'm wondering the same thing. Can you clarify what you mean by "I have a problem with removing subtasks in my to-do app."?

Comment: Removing seems to work well

Comment: I just edited my question. I want to remove selected subtask from "Domain", instead handleRemoveSubtasks removes all of the subtasks together.

Answer (score 2):

There are various problems:

- `handleRemoveSubtasks` tries to access `el.tasks` even if it doesnt exist, so it throws an error.
- `handleRemoveSubtasks` filter is returned as the own `el` element, instead of the `el.tasks`

Check the following code:

```
  const handleRemoveSubtasks = subtaskId => {
    useList(
      list.map(el => {
        if (!el.tasks) return el // If no tasks, return the same element
        return {...el, tasks: el.tasks.filter(task => task.id !== subtaskId)} // if tasks, filter them by id
      })
    );
  };
```