# More than one getItem localStorage in a state

Tags: reactjs, local-storage, state

Is it possible to have more than one `localStorage.getItem` in state?
Right now I have this:

```
const [list, useList] = useState(
    JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dictionary")) || [] //tasks in my to-do
  );
```

and I should also keep in this state my subtasks, contained in a task, with this structure:

```
- task {
   - id
   - body
   - subtasks 
     [{
      - id
      - body
     }]
}
```

Can I save also the subtasks in local storage and access them with `getItem`?

These are what I want to use to get my subtasks:

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("domain")) || []
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("range")) || []
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can have more than one array of values in local storage.   You need to set the item before you can access it though, you should also serialize the object or array to a string when saving it.

```
localStorage.setItem("dictionary", JSON.stringify([]));
localStorage.setItem("domain", JSON.stringify([]));
localStorage.setItem("range", JSON.stringify([]));

alert(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("dictionary")));
alert(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("domain")));
alert(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("range")));
```

Comment: I have setItems in different menthods

Comment: are you asking about data structures then?  How to organize the data into one object?  I'm not sure I understand your question?

Answer (score 0):

Lucky me, I saw your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59740974/removing-subtasks-in-react-with-hooks) which contains a running code snippet, you should add it here too!

From what I saw you're trying to create a tree of tasks, `dictionary` is a task and it can have subtasks such as `domain` and `range`, right? Then you should have a data structure like this:

```
singleTask = {
  id: 0,
  body: "task",
  domain: [
    {
      id: 00,
      body: "subtask domain 1"
    },
    {
      id: 01,
      body: "subtask domain 2"
    }
  ],
  range: [
    {
      id: 10,
      body: "subtask range 1"
    },
    {
      id: 11,
      body: "subtask range 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

When you're rendering a task as `TaskListItem`, you render the `task.body`. Then pass `task.domain` to a `SubtaskDomain` component, `task.range` to a `SubtaskRange` component.
When you submit a subtask, update the main list in App, after you do that, update local storage, you already do that, but you actually only need one set item, and it's

```
localStorage.setItem("dictionary", JSON.stringify(listState));
```

because you have everything in it!